# Are Azure VM Metrics Always Accurate?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, metrics

I have an Azure VM that is supposedly sized at [Standard B8ms (8 vcpus, 32 GiB memory)]. The Azure metric is pegged at 16%. When I log in to the server, the server is maxed out. The services/applications it runs have not changed, but the performance has been severely downgraded, acting like the server is really running at 17% capacity.

What steps would I take to diagnose if the issue is with the metric or is the metric correct and something is wrong with the VM.

Thanks

[Remote Session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9ZFV.png)

[Azure Metric, dip is a server reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ5JV.png)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry everyone, I did not know about CPU credits. The server ran out of CPU credits.

The B-Series uses a credit system, I will changing the server to a non-credit series:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-b-series-burstable